# Parse JSON with no title Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am pulling down a json stream? From a phant server I can pull the data down parse it and print it in xcode. I need to pull out specific values but the json does not have a title and I can not seem to figure it out.

My JSON Data

```
(
    {
    lat = "36.123450";
    long = "-97.123459";
    timestamp = "2017-04-26T05:55:15.106Z";
},
```

My Current Code in Swift

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/5JDdvbVgx6urREAVgKOM.json")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    } else {
        if let content = data {
            do {
                // JSONArray 
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                print(myJson)
                let Coordinates = myJson["lat"] as! [[String:Any]]
                print(Coordinates)


            } catch {
        }
    }
    }
}
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: lat is just s String.

Comment: What do you mean there is no title? You have an array of dictionaries. Iterate the array and for each dictionary, extract whatever key values you need.

Comment: @rmaddy I have been trying but every example I can find it has a title and thats how they have been able to extract values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the JSON. `[]` represents an array, `{}` a dictionary.

The JSON is an array of dictionaries. All keys and values are `String`.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/5JDdvbVgx6urREAVgKOM.json")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error: ", error!)
    } else {
        do {
            let coordinateArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String:String]]
            for coodinate in coordinateArray {
                let lat = coodinate["lat"] ?? "n/a"
                let long = coodinate["long"] ?? "n/a"
                let timestamp = coodinate["timestamp"] ?? "n/a"
                print("latitude: \(lat), longitude: \(long), timestamp: \(timestamp)")
            }

        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

As always, `.mutableContainers` has no effect in Swift but the tutorials which suggests that will never die off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON data is an array of objects, so `myJson` will be an array of dictionaries.

I would try something like this:

```
if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [AnyObject] {
    print(myJson)
    for obj in myJson {
        if let dict = obj as? [String:AnyObject] {
            print(dict)
            if let lat = dict["lat"] as? String,
                let lng = dict["long"] as? String,
                let time = dict["timestamp"] as? String {
                    // do something with stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```